# Power BI (Power Query M) Linear Interpolation Over Time Series Data

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am pulling data into Power BI and transforming it with Power Query M, and it is currently in the following format:

| State | County | Date | Population | Sub-Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-01 | 104 | 38 |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-02 | 103 | 38 |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-03 | 108 | 36 |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-04 | *null* | 33 |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-05 | *null* | *null* |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-06 | *null* | *null* |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-07 | 116 | *null* |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-08 | 115 | 31 |
| CA | Los Angeles | 2020-05-21 | 866 | 112 |
| CA | Los Angeles | 2020-05-22 | 871 | 119 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

I want to conduct simple linear interpolations over null dates in each of my columns, such that I output data like:

| State | County | Date | Population | Sub-Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-01 | 104 | 38 |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-02 | 103 | 38 |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-03 | 108 | 36 |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-04 | *110* | 33 |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-05 | *112* | *32.5* |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-06 | *114* | *32* |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-07 | 116 | *31.5* |
| NY | New York | 2020-01-08 | 115 | 31 |
| CA | Los Angeles | 2020-05-21 | 866 | 112 |
| CA | Los Angeles | 2020-05-22 | 871 | 119 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

Is there a simple way to do this in Power Query M, without having to construct a function that explicitly defines what a linear interpolation is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt the code found [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Quick-Measures-Gallery/Linear-Interpolation/m-p/330712)

But essential you'd create a measure with the following syntax:

```
Interpolated Value = 
VAR x3 = MAX(Dates[Date])
    VAR match = CALCULATE(MAX('Event Duration Prediction'[Duration]);FILTER('Event Duration Prediction';'Event Duration Prediction'[Date]=x3))
    VAR x1 = CALCULATE(MAX('Event Duration Prediction'[Date]);FILTER('Event Duration Prediction';'Event Duration Prediction'[Date]<=x3))
    VAR x2 = CALCULATE(MIN('Event Duration Prediction'[Date]);FILTER('Event Duration Prediction';'Event Duration Prediction'[Date]>=x3))
    VAR y1 = CALCULATE(MAX('Event Duration Prediction'[Duration]);FILTER('Event Duration Prediction';'Event Duration Prediction'[Date]<=x3))
    VAR y2 = CALCULATE(MIN('Event Duration Prediction'[Duration]);FILTER('Event Duration Prediction';'Event Duration Prediction'[Date]>=x3))
    RETURN IF(NOT(ISBLANK(match));match;y1 + (x3 - x1) * (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))
```

Let me know if this was helpful!